# Is it common for professors in The Netherlands to change institutions as they go up the ranks, or to speed up the promotion process?

Tags: tenure-track, netherlands, promotion

I have heard that it is common for Assistant Professors or Associate Professors in The Netherlands to apply for positions at other Dutch institutions to improve their chances of promotion. Is this information correct?

Comment: So you mean: (A) I apply at another university, but I do not intend to go there.  If I get an offer of employment from them, I will show it to my current institution, and hope for a matching offer.  Or (B), to get promoted from Associate to Full, I do it by switching to another university.

Comment: More like (b). I am Assistant Professor and I apply for an Associate Professor position elsewhere to "pressure" (for lack of a better term) my institution to promote me earlier, or simply to gain promotion at a different institution a year or two prior to the time I would promote at my university. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: More like (b). I am Assistant Professor and I apply for an Associate Professor position elsewhere to "pressure" (for lack of a better term) my institution to promote me earlier, or simply to gain promotion at a different institution a year or two prior to the time I would promote at my university. Is this possible? Thanks.